# Understanding opencv's decomposeHomographyMat outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0, homography

I'm trying to find the angle required to move my camera so it's directly in front of an object. If my camera is looking at the object at a 30 degree angle from the left, then my script should return 30 degrees. I'm using cv2.decomposeHomographyMat to find a rotation matrix which works fine. There are 4 solutions returned from this function, so in my script I am outputting 4 angles. Of these angles, there are only two unique angles. My problem is I don't know which of these two angles is correct.

I know the decomposeHomographyMat returns four possible solutions, but shouldn't the angles be the same? I also found the coordinates of my points projected on a 2D plane, but I wasn't sure what to do with this information in regards to finding which angle is correct (here pts3D are the 2D points of the object taken from the camera image with a 0 added for the z column making it 3D pts):

```
for i in range(len(Ts)):
    projectedPts = cv2.projectPoints(pts3D, Rs[i], Ts[i], CAM_MATRIX, DIST_COEFFS)[0][:,0,:]
```

Here is a snippet from my code. Maybe I am incorrectly determining the angles from the rotation matrix? In my example below, y1 and y2 will be the same angle, and y3 and y4 will be the same angle. Can someone help explain how I determine which angle is the correct angle, and why there are two different angles returned?

```
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):
    sy = math.sqrt(Rs[0][0] * R[0][0] +  R[1][0] * R[1][0])
    singular = sy < 1e-6

    if  not singular :
        x = math.atan2(R[2][1] , R[2][2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2][0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1][0], R[0][0])
    else :
        x = math.atan2(-R[1][2], R[1][1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2][0], sy)
        z = 0
    return np.rad2deg(y)



H, status = cv2.findHomography(corners, REFPOINTS)

output = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, H, (800,800))

# Rs returns 4 matricies, we use the first one
_, Rs, Ts, Ns = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(H, CAM_MATRIX)


y1 = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Rs[0])
y2 = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Rs[1])
y3 = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Rs[2])
y4 = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Rs[3])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you compute the current object pose using for instance `solvePnP()`? If so, you should be able to compute the homography that allows transforming from the current view to the desired view. There is also a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html) in OpenCV that could bring some information.